# Java Streams - Sort if Comparator exists

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I have a class where **optionally** a `Comparator` can be specified.

---

Since the `Comparator` is optional, I have to evaluate its presence and execute the same stream code, either with `sorted()` or without:

```
if(comparator != null) {
    [...].stream().map()[...].sorted(comparator)[...];
} else {
    [...].stream().map()[...];
}
```

**Question:**
Is there a more elegant way to do this without the code duplication?

**Note:**
A default `Comparator` is not an option, I just want to keep the original order of the values I am streaming.

Besides, the elements are already mapped at the point of sorting, so I can not somehow reference the root list of the stream, as I do not have the original elements anymore.

Comment: Select `[...].stream().map()[...]` and choose your IDE "extract variable" refactoring maybe?

Comment: `[...].stream().map()[...].sorted((a,b) -> comparator == null ? 0 : comparator.compare(a,b))[...];`

Comment: You can put the stream instance in a variable ( `Stream` class) and then if a comparator is present, call the sort method of that class? Then collect the result....

Comment: @Lino: more efficient would be `.sorted(comparator == null? (a,b) -> 0: comparator)`, not repeating the `null`-check in every comparison. Still, it implies an unnecessary sorting process when `comparator` is `null`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Stream<Something> stream = [...].stream().map()[...]; // preliminary processing
if(comparator != null) {
    stream = stream.sorted(comparator); // optional sorting
}
stream... // resumed processing, which ends in some terminal operation (such as collect)
```

Comment: How does this make the above code better? In fact, if you are using Streams it's always a good practice to chain in one statement.

Comment: Oh my, thank you. I was so focused on an inline solution I did not think about this.

Comment: @AshishLohia Uhmm... allow me to disagree with you. This approach is readable and correct.

Comment: @AshishLohia why is it always better to do it in one statement? This would lead to duplication of the map, which is worse.

Comment: @Ashish Lohia: it’s a good practice to chain in one statement, but that doesn’t imply that it is always the best practice. You have to trade off between that good practice and the other food practice, avoiding code duplication…

Comment: I have to honestly admit that I often forget (the question is a proof) that a stream can be assigned to a variable as it is just a normal class instance. It's somehow this thinking of chaining the stream operations that let's you forget this from my pov.

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be to use `Optional`:

```
Stream<Whatever> stream = [...].stream().map()[...];

List<WhateverElse> result = Optional.ofNullable(comparator)
    .map(stream::sorted)
    .orElse(stream)
    .[...] // <-- go on with the stream pipeline
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Also a great idea to keep the functional syntax.

Comment: @JDC Thank you! Yes, that was my idea, however you shouldn't use `Optional` this way all the time. Stuart Marks and Brian Goetz (parents of this `Optional` creature) recommend to not use `Optional` only for method chaining. Instead, they say that you should use it ideally as the return value of methods, where the returned value might be null. I think that this fits your use case, because you might have a method that returns an `Optional` wrapping your nullable comparator.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a comparator of your type (I used E as a placeholder here) that will not change the order:

```
 Comparator<E> NO_SORTING = (one, other) -> 0;
```

If the comparator field is an Optional of Comparator, you can then use

```
.sorted(comparator.orElse(NO_SORTING))
```

Comment: Returning `0` means the objects are equal. Is it guaranteed that the stream sorting does not shift around equal objects?

Comment: I would not expect it to, but you would have to consult the documentation, @JDC. Good question.

Comment: The documentation of `.sorted()` states it is at least stable for ordered streams. The order of equal elements should be kept then. So the mentioned answer is indeed correct for ordered streams.

Comment: It's correct, but it could come at a significant cost. Sorting is a relatively expensive operation and it's entirely unnecessary here.

Comment: @shmosel Thats true. Personally I'd never sort a stream anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind use third party library [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
StreamEx(source).[...].chain(s -> comparator == null ? s : s.sorted(comparator)).[...];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using an auxiliary function.

```
static <T, R> R applyFunction(T obj, Function<T, R> f) {
    return f.apply(obj);
}
```

and

```
applyFunction([...].stream().map()[...],
    stream -> comparator == null ? stream : stream.sorted(comparator))
    [...];
```

You don't need to know intermediate stream type.